# Write input to file, excluding final line

Tags: python-3.x, file, for-loop, while-loop

My simple assignment is to write a function that asks for a filename, and then repeatedly reads lines from the user and saves these lines to the named file.

It stops saving the lines when the user input is a single dot on a line by itself. The line containing the single dot is NOT saved.

Example output would look like:

```
Save to what file: mytest.txt
> This is
> my attempt at
> the problem.
>
> The last line was empty
> .
Saving file mytest.txt
5 lines saved
```

Here's my attempt:

```
def savefile():
    filename = input("Save to what file: ")
    infile = open(filename, "w")
    line = ""
    lineCount = 0
    while line != ".":
        line = input("> ")
        infile.write(line + "\n")
        lineCount += 1


    print("Saving file", filename)
    print(lineCount, "lines saved")

    infile.close()
```

which works fine, except my `while` loop also saves the last line (the "." by itself on a line). I've also tried an `if`-`else` loop:

```
if line != ".":
    line = input("> ")
    infile.write(line + "\n")
    lineCount += 1
else:
    infile.close()
```

but this just saves the first line entered.

How can I exclude the last line entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't even need an explanation:

```
with open("my_file.txt","w") as file:
    while True:
        line = input("> ")
        if line.strip() == ".":
            break
        else:
            file.write(line + "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this by simply interchanging some of the lines in your code as follows:

```
def savefile():
    filename = input("Save to what file: ")
    infile = open(filename, "w")
    line = input("> ")
    lineCount = 0
    while line != ".":
        infile.write(line + "\n")
        lineCount += 1
        line = input("> ")


    print("Saving file", filename)
    print(lineCount, "lines saved")

    infile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is just a little out of order, classic problem, move the input to above the while loop, I hope see why...

```
def savefile():
    filename = input("Save to what file: ")
    infile = open(filename, "w")
    line = ""
    lineCount = 0
    # first lets get the line of input
    line = input("> ")
    # if the line is "." then don't do the following code.
    while line != ".":
        # if the line was not "." then we do this...
        infile.write(line + "\n")
        lineCount += 1
        # get the input again, and loop, remember if we get "."
        # we will break from this loop.
        line = input("> ")


    print("Saving file", filename)
    print(lineCount, "lines saved")

    infile.close()
```

Comment: I see why `line = input"> "` must be before the loop, but when I do this, the function enters what looks like an infinite loop, never getting to the "save file" stage. Why is that?

Comment: I added comments to the code, I hope it helps clear things up.